# VideoCastControllerActivity: ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-cast, castcompanionlibrary

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.newco.cooltv.qa/com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.player.VideoCastControllerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

i am using cast companion library and tried both way

(1) Add this library from jCenter repo by adding the following line to your project's dependencies:

(2) Use the GitHub source and include that as a module dependency by following these steps:

Both are failing with above exception after call to

```
 loadRemoteMedia(mediaInfo, 0, true);
```

in build.gradle i have specified below dependencies

```
//  lib for chromecast    
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.3.0'   
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.0.2'  
compile project(':CastCompanionLibrary')
```

I am using Andorid Studio 2.1.2 and updated build.gradle of CCL with

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare that in your Manifest file, something like:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.player.VideoCastControllerActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >    
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```